# Animated View scaling only half of the screen width

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Animated.View is only scaling to the half of the screen width provided.
Secondly, why do I have to give width in the stylesheet for this to work and what is the particular reason for giving it length 1.
If I increase the width in stylesheet to 2 the Progress Bar covers the entire screen width

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { View, Animated, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Easing } from 'react-native'

export default class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        percent: new Animated.Value(0)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.startAnimation()
    }

    startAnimation = () => {
        this.animation = Animated.timing(this.state.percent, {
            toValue: 100,
            duration: this.props.timeRemaining*1000,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        })

        this.animation.start()
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Animated.View 
                style={[
                    styles.bar,
                    {transform: [{
                        scaleX: this.state.percent.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [0, 100],
                            outputRange: [0, Dimensions.get('window').width]
                        })
                    }] }
                ]}
            />

            // <View style={[styles.bar, {width: Dimensions.get('window').width}]}/>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bar: {
        height: 30,
        width: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'tomato',
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

as I said in [Animated View scaling only half of the screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667787/animated-view-scaling-only-half-of-the-screen-width/63668833#63668833) half of your `<Animated.View>` is out of your screen and you are not able to see it.
use TranslateX to solve it.
this is working for me:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

export default function () {
  const timer = new Animated.Value(0);
  const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");

  const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(timer, {
      duration: 2000,
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      isInteraction: false,
    }).start();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    startAnimation()
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        {
          width,
          height: 5,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: timer.interpolate(
                {
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [-width / 2, 0],
                }
              ),
            },
            {
         // you can use scaleX : timer if you don't need interpolation
              scaleX: timer.interpolate(
                {
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [0, 1],
                }
              ),
            },
          ],
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of interpolating from [0,1] to [0,1] ?

Comment: as I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667787/animated-view-scaling-only-half-of-the-screen-width/63668833#63668833 : ScaleX multiplies a number by item width. in this example my item width is Dimensions.get("window").width, then at first my item width will be 0 because scaleX is 0 and width * 0 = 0 , and as the Animation progresses my scale number increases  (and item width increases ) until it reaches 1 then my item width will be :  width * 1 =  Dimensions.get("window").width

Comment: You answer did not addressed my question. anyway the answer is that there is no point in interpolating from [0,1] to [0,1]

Comment: I think both of my answers was clear, and I have find my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667787/animated-view-scaling-only-half-of-the-screen-width/63681953#63681953 code in one of the best react native libraries.but if you think "there is no point in interpolating from [0,1] to [0,1]" you should talk with theirs best programmers :)   anyway, the choice is yours

Comment: and your main questions was: 1.why Animated.View is only scaling to the half of the screen width 2.why do I have to give width in the stylesheet  ... and I have answered both of them correctly. and if you want a code that solve your problem, I have searched and tested some solutions and this one was one of the bests. It shows politeness if you thank someone who has given so much time to help you. Good luck

Comment: You are confusing. It was not my question so I am not the one who should thank you for your effort. I only asked what is the point of interpolating [0,1] to [0,1]..

Comment: your main question in your post was not about interpolating, it was that 2 questions that I mentioned above. and for your new question, the answer is that I have used interpolation because I wanted users(people who use this answer) to be able to change initial value (for example from 0 to 0.1 if they want their ProgressBar to be visible at first ) or any change they want to do. if you don't want to change it you can use " scaleX: timer " instead of it

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just needed a little clarification and your response helped me understand it. BTW I think you are confusing me with @D10S